# Unformatted hyperlinks appearing a lot more often?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Is there a reason why many users have started including links in their raw, unformatted form?

I see them in a lot of questions and answers lately.

I don't know the official policy on this, but they don't look as good as formatted links.

Is this type of practice something that could be a cause of concern if it continues to rise significantly?

Comment: Like... where? If a user doesn't include "http://" I don't think anything gets auto-formatted.

Comment: @Scott from what I understand, when links are formatted like this the no-follow rule doesn't apply (at least it's not as hindering), and they still benefit SEO-wise. It may not be a problem now but it could be an attractive option for spammers if all links were to be formatted like that. It's already difficult to get rid of spam answers when they're slightly related to a post, yet they often require editing. Now what if users started posting LQ but not off-topic questions related to their product, and then posted links to their product

Comment: I think I read/heard somewhere that the `[hyperlink](formatting)` helps to discourage spammers because it provides no SEO benefits, but I can't recall where.

Comment: [Here's an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236628/216955) on how `nofollow` is handled

Comment: @JohnB thanks for that, it gives some hints but I'm still wondering about the unformatted links a little. I'm going to see if I can find anything referring to what I've said above. May pop in to chat later as well.

Comment: I prefer hyperlinks to be formatted and will usually make that edit if I see a raw link. Whether or not raw links are appearing more often, I don't know how to definitively answer that.

Comment: @JohnB I can't even figure out how to query it because searching for `http://` also shows posts where the body contains formatted hyperlinks (when it's part of the markdown like `[blah](http://blah.com)`).